# Emacs : install auto-complete issues

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

I have some issues with the installation of autocompletion on emacs 24.5.

I cloned https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete.git repo in my .emacs.d folder located here : `C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d`

I run :
 `M-x load-file C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d\auto-complete\etc\install.el` and anwser to install it in : `C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d\lisp`
Emacs answered : `Successfully installed!`

Then I add the following lines to my .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "c:/Users/Ben/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/lisp")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
```

When I run emacs, I have the following error  :

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `c:/Users/Ben/AppData/Roaming/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, popup.
```

Here is my complete .emacs file :

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))

(add-to-list 'load-path "c:/Users/Ben/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/lisp")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
```

What's wrong ? How to install auto-complete on emacs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the popup library: https://github.com/auto-complete/popup-el

You also need this: https://github.com/tjarvstrand/pos-tip